# What does XXX stand for in facebook graph's mention tagging format @[ID:XXX:NAME]?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For an album description where another facebook page is tagged/mentioned,
I'm getting back this value:
`"Some description text @[PAGE-ID:XXX:PAGE-NAME]"`

`XXX` is a 3 digit number, but I can't find any info on what this number stands for.
Everywhere I only see the `@[PAGE-ID:PAGE-NAME]` format.

What's the best way to parse this format. Should my parser expect `@[PAGE-ID:PAGE-NAME]` and `@[PAGE-ID:XXX:PAGE-NAME]`?

For what it might be worth, the response I'm seeing when opening the graph URL through the Chrome browser is `Some description text \u0040[PAGE-ID:XXX:PAGE-NAME]`, so \u0040 instead of @.

Comment: Can you show some example screenshot may be?

Comment: Unfortunately can't use my specific example since it's work in progress. Looking for another example I can share. Might be something that is only in album descriptions. In wall photos tagged pages are returned in plain text in the "name" field and additional return a "name_tags" field with the tag data. Will report back if I find another example, thanks so far!

Comment: Also, technically, the exact response I'm getting is \u0040[PAGE-ID:XXX:PAGE-NAME]. Will update the post.